# Any ontolgy or api for job titles?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

Basically what I need is to determine the category of the job title that the user will freely enter.

Is there any ontology or api that provides this?

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I did a lot of research and did not find any ontology for that. I would appreciate before you downgrade a question you make an effort to ask about what is not clear for you. For me it seems very clear.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mayor2.dia.fi.upm.es/oeg-upm/index.php/en/ontologies/99-hrmontology). Based on the description it may be useful in a reduced form.

Comment: Thank you Kunal i saw it when i was searching but i just noticed that their ontology is publicly available. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! if its helpful, I'll put it in an answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 3):

The Human Resources Management Ontology, will act as a common "language" in the form of a set of controlled vocabularies to describe the details of a job posting and the CV of a job seeker. The ontology is located [here](http://mayor2.dia.fi.upm.es/oeg-upm/index.php/en/ontologies/99-hrmontology)